# Usage of "storage" and "memory" keywords in struct declaration

Tags: solidity

I have recently ported my code to solidity 0.4.11 and have been noticing some warning errors upon declaring 'string' variables while declaring structs.

```
struct person {
    string name;
    string physicalAddress;
}
```

the warning I have been getting is:

`Variable is declared as a storage pointer. Use an explicit "storage" keyword to silence the warning.`

Suggestions on how to get rid of this warning? Also I am trying to understand the usage of storage and memory keywords - could anyone help explain the utility patterns of these keywords?

Comment: at least you sould not use address as a variable name

Answer (score 6):

This issue has been reported before in github and it was fixed in the patch below
https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/2551. Therefore, the solution is to upgrade your compiler.
 **NB** : the compiler 0.4.14 is out since (2017-07-31)

.

Comment: thanks for the response! do you suggest updating the compiler version to 0.4.13 or 0.4.14 instead?

Comment: 0.4.14 is still unavailable https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md
0.4.13 didn't solve the problem

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios what version do you use?

Comment: @BadrBellaj Im using Mist 0.9.

Comment: Was it really fixed? I see this on their GitHub site: